# why does extending PDO causes me a memory overflow?

Tags: php, database, class, pdo

i have a class that extends the PDO class. it's called Database. but in a particular function, the commit() function, it gets an memory overflow error.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261900 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\igadgets\application\includes\base\classes\database.php on line 130
```

the function was:

```
function commit() {
    return $this->commit();
}
```

the curious is: when i change my class to not extend PDO anymore, but just contain it in a variable, the error disappears.

this works fine:

```
function commit() {
    return $this->pdo->commit();
}
```

why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is simple.  Your code is wrong.  It's doing infinite recursion.

When you call `$this->commit()`, you're calling that very same method.  So it will just loop on forever until either you run out of memory, or you overflow the stack (hit a StackOverflow, hehehe).

Instead, change the function to call the parent class's `commit()` method (which in this case is: `PDO::commit()`):

```
function commit() {
    return parent::commit();
}
```